# Angular JS : Error: $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop

Tags: angularjs

i have this error when i put  in controller

> "$rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop"

Controller:

```js
$scope.List = ["hello", "patrick", "daniel", " jemmy", "lara", "said", "charle", "ridha.", "radhi", "fred"
  $scope.GetRandomListName = function() {
    return $scope.List[Math.floor((Math.random() * List.lenght))];
  }
];
```

CHTML:

```html
<div class="row">
  <blockquote>
    {{GetRandomListName()}}
  </blockquote>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. and **explain why the result is not what you expected**.  Edit your question to include the error messages and locations, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you please share jsfiddle or plukr for this?

Comment: hello this is a link of jsfiddler : https://jsfiddle.net/9dq81pn4/

Comment: have you an idea please

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS invokes `GetRandomListName` not once, but several times until results will be same. At your case, you can't achieve it, because your function generates random numbers each time, it leads to *"$rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop"*. So, you should `cache` results - for that you also should provide argument(`index`), because you can have several `{{GetRandomListName}}` expressions, and you should track relation between `cache[index]` and corresponding `{{GetRandomListName(index)}}`:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.List = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    $scope.List.push(i);
    
  var cache = [];
  $scope.GetRandomListName = function(index) {            
    return cache[index] 
      || (cache[index] = $scope.List[Math.floor((Math.random() * $scope.List.length))]);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <p>First: {{GetRandomListName(0)}}</p>
  <p>Second: {{GetRandomListName(1)}}</p>
</div>
```